Maximum Length of Tangent to Circle
A circle passes through $\left(3,4\right)$ and $\left(10,11\right)$:

What will be the maximum length of tangent to it from $\left(2,3\right)$ ?.


I approached it via taking the smallest circle through the given points and then calculates the length of tangent which came out to be negative and unreal.

Any help is appreciated.

Back of the envelope gives a tangent distance of 4 for the smallest circle...

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent%E2%80%93secant_theorem

Note that the point in question lies on the radical axis of the pencil of circles generated by the two points in question, which all have the same power to a point on that axis.

It's worth noting that the three given points are collinear. By the way, if they hadn't been, this looks like it would be quite an interesting problem to do with Lagrange multipliers.

Looking at Bipolar coordinates (Wiki) all circles through two fixed "foci"have the same tangent length from the origin.

Let $A=(2,3)$, $B=(3,4)$, and $C=(10,11)$. Now, consider two arbitrary circles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ passing through $B$ and $C$, with their tangent points from $A$ being $P$ and $Q$. Since $A$, $B$, and $C$ are collinear, Power of a Point tells us:
$$AP^2=AB\cdot AC=AQ^2,$$
so in fact the length of the tangent from $A$ to any two circles passing through $B$ and $C$ is the same! Thus, the distance is the same for all possible circles, so the constant "maximum" value is $AP=\sqrt{AB\cdot AC}=4.$
Note: We can also prove this by observing that $A$ lies on the radical axis of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, so the power with respect to each circle is the same.

Nice catch! Collinear! +1

See my answer which has common features with yours.

Let $A(3,4)$, $B(10,11)$ and $C(2,3)$.
The fact that $A,B,C$ are aligned is essential.
I have already given an answer to a similar question here.
Here is a qualitative presentation of this result.
First of all, have a look at the Wikipedia article here.

Fig. 1 : (Apollonian) pencil of circles $(P_1)$ in blue and its orthogonal pencil $(P_2)$ in red. The green circle is the set of points of tangency.
The circles passing through $A$ and $B$ constitute a so-called pencil $(P_1)$. We just have to consider the orthogonal pencil $(P_2)$ (the set of circles orthogonal to all circles of $(P_1)$). The centers of these circles are on line $AB$. One of them is the looked for locus (featured in green in Fig. 1).
The set of points $X$ is part of this circle (in fact all the circle except a point).
Remark 1: using Wikipedia's terminology, $(P_1)$ is an elliptical pencil and $(P_2)$ a hyperbolic pencil.
Remark 2: I would like to add here an element of methodology for obtaining analytic expressions for the two Apollonian pencils.
Let us consider a "prototype" of such a pencil : the set of circles passing through $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ (on the left of Fig. 2) with plain equations :
$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2-2ax+1&=&0\\x^2+y^2-2by-1&=&0 \end{cases}$$
[One can check the classical orthogonality condition :
$$a_1a_2+b_1b_2=\tfrac12(c+c')$$
which is here :
$$a \times 0 + 0 \times b = \tfrac12(1+(-1))]$$
In order to get the "new" equations, we just  to use the rigid change of coordinates :
$$\begin{cases}x'&=& \ \ px+qy+r\\y'&=&-qx+py+s \end{cases}\tag{2}$$
mapping points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ onto points $(3,4)$ and $(10,11)$ resp.
(taking into account that (2), considered as a change of coordinates is to be interpreted "backwards" : $(x',y')$ are the old coordinates.). See program below.

Fig. 2 : The first family of Apollonian pencils and their image by a certain affine transform.
SAGE program for Fig. 2:
 var('p q r s x y xx yy')
 L=-5;M=15
 g=line(((L,0),(-L,0)),color='black')
 g+=line(((0,L),(0,-L)),color='black')
 for a in range(20):
    a1=(a)/4-5;
    g+=implicit_plot(x^2+y^2-2*a1*x+1==0,(x,L,-L),(y,L,-L))
 for b in range(10):
    b1=(b-5)/4;
    g+=implicit_plot(x^2+y^2-2*b1*y-1==0,(x,L,-L),(y,L,-L),color='red')
 show(g)
 # second figure :
 g=line(((0,1),(10,11)),color='black')
 g+=line(((L,0),(M,0)),color='black')
 g+=line(((0,L),(0,M)),color='black')
 p=1/7;q=1/7;s=-1/7;r=-2;
 xx=p*x+q*y+r
 yy=-q*x+p*y+s
 for a in range(20):
    a1=(a)/4-5;
    g+=implicit_plot(xx^2+yy^2-2*a1*xx+1==0,(x,L,M),(y,L,M))
 for b in range(10):
    b1=(b-5)/4;
    g+=implicit_plot(xx^2+yy^2-2*b1*yy-1==0,(x,L,M),(y,L,M),color='red')
 show(g)

with the special program for obtaining coefficients $p,q,r,s$ :
 sl=solve([3*p+4*q+r==-1,-3*q+4*p+s==0,10*p+11*q+r==1,-10*q+11*p+s==0],p,q,r,s)


Hint:
WLOG, the equation of the circle $$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$
where the center $O(-f,-g),$ radius $=\sqrt{f^2+g^2-c}$
As the circle passes through $(3,4);(10,11)$ we can replace the values of $(x,y)$ and solve for $f,g$ in terms of $c$  to find $2f=59-c, 2g=c-87 \iff c=2g+87, f=-14-g$
We need to maximize $$\underbrace{f^2+g^2-c}_{\text{ the square of the radius}}+\underbrace{(-f-2)^2+(-g-3)^2}_{\text{the square of the distance of }(2,3) \text{ from the center}}=2f^2+2g^2+4f+6g+13-c$$
Replace the values of $f,c$ in terms of $g$
Can you form a perfect square with $c$ and take it home?

The center of the circle lies on the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining $(3,4)$ and $(10,11)$. Therefore, the center is $O(a,-a+14)$ for some $a\in\Bbb R$ and the equation of the circle is
$F(x,y)=(x-a)^2+(y+a-14)^2-(a-10)^2-(a-3)^2=0.$
The power of $(2,3)$ with respect to this circle is $F(2,3)=16>0$. So, the point $(2,3)$ lies outside of the circle and the length of the tangent of $(2,3)$ to the circle is $\sqrt{16}=4$.

A family of circles which passes through points (3,4) and (10,11)
Would be
(x-3)(x-10)+(y-4)(y-11)+λ(x-y+1)=0
And the length of tangent is given by the
Root of what comes when putting the external point into the eqn of the circle.
In this case by putting 2,3 into the above eqn we get 16 whose root is 4.
Here the point 2,3 lies on x-y+1 so the lambda term multiplies with zero so we don't bother with it.
However, if the external point did not lie on the line what would be do?
I cannot comment as my reputation is insufficient so bear with me.(I'm new here)

When you say "what comes when putting the external point into the eqn of the circle" you refer to the power of this external point with respect to any circle of the family (what I call a pencil of circles in my answer)
